# how to sending big data array using for loop statement via Ajax

Tags: javascript, ajax, arrays, for-loop

I'm learning javascript programming.

My js code works.
But one problem is that the below code simplified to ask send big data to server Almost simultaneously.
I want to send data one by one.
How to fix it by using closure ? :-)

```
$("#dataupload").click(function(){

    for (var i = 0 ; i < datafiles.length; i++) { 
        var f = datafiles[i] ;
        $.post("/upload.php",f,function(result){
            console.log(result);
        });
    }

});
```

Comment: I don't know enough as to answer, but I think you are looking for recursive functions here.

Comment: How does the for loop terminate?

Comment: Besides, I recommend not to do it in this way. The biggest delay in html requests are the requests themself (asking for the page and sending headers/etc), not the data being sent. So, unless you have huge data (I'm talking about mbs here), I'd recommend sending all the data at once.

Comment: Sorry, I edited code correctly. Each datum is bigger than 10mb. because the server machine does not have enough resources to analyze data at once, client has to wait for response from server to send the next.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to do it serially, you can do something like this:

```
(function send(i) {
    if(i < datafiles.length) {
        $.post("/upload.php", datafiles[i], function(result) {
            console.log(result);
            send(++i);   
        });
    }
})(0);
```

Here `send` is a function that is part of an immediately-invoked function-expression. We're replicating a loop here by using the callback. Although we are calling `send` here it is important to note that this isn't strictly recursive, since the subsequent call to `send` is note done while `send` itself is executing, but is called when the callback of `$.post` is executed.

`send` takes one argument, which is an index into your `datafiles` array. If `i` is lesser than the length of the array, it means that we still have files to send. We make a call to `$.post`, and in the callback, we increment the value of `i` and call `send` again with the new value of `i`. When `i` becomes equal to the length of the `datafiles` array, it means that we are done.